# Невозможно записать метод в событие OnClick с помощью цикла

Tags: c#, unity3d, события

Вот так работает и приводит к запланированному:

```
    controller.moviesListPlayer[0].GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
    {
        performer.MoveWasSelect();
        performer.healingMovies[0].HealMove(this);
    });
    controller.moviesListPlayer[1].GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
    {
        performer.MoveWasSelect();
        performer.healingMovies[1].HealMove(this);
    });
    controller.moviesListPlayer[2].GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
    {
        performer.MoveWasSelect();
        performer.healingMovies[2].HealMove(this);
    });
    controller.moviesListPlayer[3].GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
    {
        performer.MoveWasSelect();
        performer.healingMovies[3].HealMove(this);
    });
```

А так не работает (выводит ошибку о индексе вне массива ЕСЛИ событие onClick срабатывает):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        controller.moviesListPlayer[i].GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
            {
                performer.MoveWasSelect();
                performer.healingMovies[i].HealMove(this);
            });
    }
```

Вопрос: почему?

Длина массивов `moviesListPlayer` и `healingMovies` статична и я устанавливал её вручную. Все элементы обоих массивов не являются null и принимаю те значения, которые мне нужны.
Сразу скажу, что сам цикл проходит гладко и проблемы появляются ТОЛЬКО если событие onClick сработает!

Comment: Такие ошибки устраняются с помощью отладки. Почитайте про точки останова, про пошаговое выполнение кода, про контроль значений переменных, а потом используйте эти знания в работе.

Comment: А я ведь даже заметил, что тестовая функция, выводящая i после цикла выводит одно и тоже значение, но не обратил особого внимания...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо скопировать переменную `i` в локальную переменную прежде чем её использовать, потому что во время вызова события цикл уже закончился и `i` равно 4.
Попробуйте так:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int iCopy = i;
    controller.moviesListPlayer[iCopy].GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
    {
        performer.MoveWasSelect();
        performer.healingMovies[iCopy].HealMove(this);
    });
}
```

Comment: Комментарий для ТС - почитайте о "замыкании", что бы понять, почему так происходит.